# CSS mapping issue in Google App Engine

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, url-routing, yaml

I'm writing a python webapp application for Google App Engine and I'm having some issues with the URL mapping. For some reason, we wanted to put the index.html file inside another folder (not in the same folder with the main.py file). Everything worked fine except that we can't access our CSS file. This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: testApp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers: 

- url: /css
  static_dir: test/gui/css

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico))
  static_files: test/\1
  upload: test/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico))

- url: /game/.*
  script: game.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

This is my URL mapping in main.py:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)
                            ], debug=True, config=config)
```

This is how my files are structured:
    
main.py
    
/test/index.html
    
/test/gui/css/stylesheets.css <-- the file that I wanted to access
    
/test/gui/images <-- the images in this folder can be accessed without any problems

I've tried googling and browsing through the posts in Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any working solutions yet. Your help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is your  statement that accesses the css files in your HTML code?  It should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css_file_1.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to append a slash:

```
- url: /css/
  static_dir: test/gui/css
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! I've tried your suggestion, however I still can't access the css file (I got a 404 not found error).